# Array index out of range in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift

In my LeftViewController which was slide out menu,there was table view
I am creating table header for each variable which will apply in table cell

```
var locals:[Local]=[Local(title: "Market",image:"ic_cars_black_24dp.png"),
                   Local(title: "Compare", image: "ic_bar_chart_24dp.png"),
                   Local(title: "Wishes",image: "ic_fantasy_24dp.png"),
                   Local(title: "Buy",image: "ic_put_in_24dp.png")]

var globals:[Global]=[Global(title: "Auction Latest",image:"ic_cars_black_24dp.png"),
                   Global(title: "Auction Past", image: "ic_bar_chart_24dp.png"),
                   Global(title: "Auction Recent",image: "ic_fantasy_24dp.png"),
                   Global(title: "Buy",image: "ic_put_in_24dp.png")]
```

These are my function that concern with UITableView

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.locals.count + self.globals.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerMenuCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderMenuCell") as HeaderMenuCell

    switch(section){
    case 0:
        headerMenuCell.headerMenuLabel.text="Local"
    case 1:
        headerMenuCell.headerMenuLabel.text="Auction"
    default:
        headerMenuCell.headerMenuLabel.text="Others"
    }

    return headerMenuCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as Cell
    switch(indexPath.section){
    case 0:
        cell.configureForLocal(locals[indexPath.row])
    case 1:
        cell.configureForGlobal(globals[indexPath.row])
    default:
        cell.textLabel?.text="Others"
    }
    return cell
}
```

This is my Cell class

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageNameLabel: UILabel!

func configureForLocal(locals: Local) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: locals.image)
    imageNameLabel.text = locals.title
}

func configureForGlobal(globals: Global) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: globals.image)
    imageNameLabel.text = globals.title
}
```

}

Please help,why i am occuring array index out of range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` has a section argument which is the section for which it wants the row count—you need to return the correct count for the specified section, not the total count for all sections.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0: return locals.count
    case 1: return globals.count
    default: fatalError("unknown section")
    }
}
```

Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: "var globals:[Global]=[Global(title: "Auction Latest",image:"ic_cars_black_24dp.png"),
                       Global(title: "Auction Past", image: "ic_bar_chart_24dp.png"),
                       Global(title: "Auction Recent",image: "ic_fantasy_24dp.png")]" If i set like this,that error occour again when i return "4" in numberOfRowInSection.

Comment: You need to return the appropriate count for the requested section, whether that's the global section or the local section.

Comment: now i got 4 rows in local section and 3 rows in global section,what should i return in numberOfRowInSection sir?

Comment: i got it now,Thank you sir.